# RaiseCanExecuteChanged not Working In Compiled exe But Does Work when Debugging

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I have absolutely ***no*** idea what's causing this.

Background: Using the Prism Framework

> 1. I have a button bound to a `DelegateCommand`
> 2. I call `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`

When I start the app in debugging mode in Visual Studio, ***everything works perfectly***. The app runs perfectly.

When I then open the app via the .exe, the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method is not being called. I have no idea why this would be the case. Anybody else run into a similar problem?

---

EDIT: When I *first* open the app via the .exe, `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` is called (since I set it in the constructor of my `ViewModel`). However, it is never called again.

---

Code in case it's needed:

```
private readonly DelegateCommand _buttonCommand;

public ViewModel()
{
    _buttonCommand = new DelegateCommand(Button, CanExecuteButton);
}

public DelegateCommand ButtonCommand
{
    get { return this._buttonCommand; }
}

public void Button()
{
    ... do stuff ...
    _buttonCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}

public bool CanExecuteButton()
{
    if (some condition)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="ClickMe"
        Command="{Binding ButtonCommand}">
```

I even got desperate and tried putting an `IsEnabled` property in my Button which I bound to `CanExecuteButton` ... to no avail.

Comment: Can you post the code of your `ButtonCommand`?

Comment: Solved, but I don't know why. It's now working...

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced similar issues with the Prism DelegateCommand.CanExeuteChanged event not being invoked.. By looking into the source code it looks like it is because it does not rely on the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested`.

Try making your own command where the event CanExecuteChanged is like so:

```
public RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private event EventHandler _canExecuteChanged;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
            _canExecuteChanged += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
            _canExecuteChanged -= value;
        }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        var handler = _canExecuteChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);

    }

    // All the other stuff also 
}
```

Now, if WPF detects changes in the UI then the CommandManager will invoke CanExecute on the command. And if something in the engineroom of the application changes, then you can invoke `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` to update CanExecute.

Comment: This didn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ButtonCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=YourView}}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```